# Opening Wordpress Gallery from a link

Tags: wordpress, gallery, lightbox

Is it possible to open a wordpress gallery using an anchor tag so that the gallery appears on the same page in a lightbox? I cannot figure out how to do so. It seems like it should be such a simple thing to do but I have tried various plug ins and cannot work out a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

first, install this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/anything-popup/

Then go to setting->anthing-pop there will be a shortcode `http://awesomescreenshot.com/03561dd759`
then click to edit it and put the [galley] shortcode

http://awesomescreenshot.com/09261ddfc0
  http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ae61ddmb5

Now use the shortcode on click see screenshot

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0de61dej39

you can use the shortcode into post or page or in file like this 
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[AnythingPopup id="1"]'); ?>`

thanks